# What is the most accurate translation of the First Noble Truth?

Tags: four-noble-truths

If I search for the 4 noble truths of Buddha on Google I get the following different translations of the first noble truth:

1. Life is suffering.
2. There is suffering in life.
3. Life is unsatisfactory.

and from the Wikipedia

4. Dukkha (suffering, incapable of satisfying, painful) is an innate characteristic of existence in the realm of samsara.

Which one is the most accurate translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

officially the noble truths are in https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.than.html

The first one in more details in https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.141.than.html

> "Now what, friends, is the noble truth of stress? Birth is stressful,
> aging is stressful, death is stressful; sorrow, lamentation, pain,
> distress, & despair are stressful; not getting what is wanted is
> stressful.[2] In short, the five clinging-aggregates are stressful.
>
> "And what is birth? Whatever birth, taking birth, descent,
> coming-to-be, coming-forth, appearance of aggregates, & acquisition of
> [sense] spheres of the various beings in this or that group of beings,
> that is called birth.
>
> "And what is aging? Whatever aging, decrepitude, brokenness, graying,
> wrinkling, decline of life-force, weakening of the faculties of the
> various beings in this or that group of beings, that is called aging.
>
> "And what is death? Whatever deceasing, passing away, breaking up,
> disappearance, dying, death, completion of time, break up of the
> aggregates, casting off of the body, interruption in the life faculty
> of the various beings in this or that group of beings, that is called
> death.
>
> "And what is sorrow? Whatever sorrow, sorrowing, sadness, inward
> sorrow, inward sadness of anyone suffering from misfortune, touched by
> a painful thing, that is called sorrow.
>
> "And what is lamentation? Whatever crying, grieving, lamenting,
> weeping, wailing, lamentation of anyone suffering from misfortune,
> touched by a painful thing, that is called lamentation.
>
> "And what is pain? Whatever is experienced as bodily pain, bodily
> discomfort, pain or discomfort born of bodily contact, that is called
> pain.
>
> "And what is distress? Whatever is experienced as mental pain, mental
> discomfort, pain or discomfort born of mental contact, that is called
> distress.
>
> "And what is despair? Whatever despair, despondency, desperation of
> anyone suffering from misfortune, touched by a painful thing, that is
> called despair.
>
> "And what is the stress of not getting what is wanted? In beings
> subject to birth, the wish arises, 'O, may we not be subject to birth,
> and may birth not come to us.' But this is not to be achieved by
> wanting. This is the stress of not getting what is wanted. In beings
> subject to aging... illness... death... sorrow, lamentation, pain,
> distress, & despair, the wish arises, 'O, may we not be subject to
> aging... illness... death... sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, &
> despair, and may aging... illness... death... sorrow, lamentation,
> pain, distress, & despair not come to us.' But this is not to be
> achieved by wanting. This is the stress of not getting what is wanted.
>
> "And what are the five clinging-aggregates that, in short, are
> stressful? The clinging-aggregate of form, the clinging-aggregate of
> feeling, the clinging-aggregate of perception, the clinging-aggregate
> of fabrications, the clinging-aggregate of consciousness: These are
> called the five clinging-aggregates that, in short, are stressful.
>
> "This, friends, is called the noble truth of stress.

Comment: Thankyou that answers the question.